# not properly getting count in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode, T_Master_Item.itemName as Description,
T_Master_Item.categoryCode as Category, 
sum(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) As Qty,
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) Good,
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Defective 
FROM T_BOE_Stock_Detail 
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Master_Item ON T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode = T_Master_Item.itemCode
WHERE T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty > 0
group by T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode, T_Master_Item.itemName,T_Master_Item.categoryCode
having sum(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) > 0 
order by T_Master_Item.categoryCode, T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode
```

my out put like this:

```
Itemcode    description   category   qty    good    defective
661-00060   Logic Board                4     2           1
```

but if I write query separate query like this:

```
select itemCode,qty,ReservedQty,DOCTYPE from T_BOE_Stock_Detail where itemCode='661-00060' and qty-ReservedQty >0
```

my out put like this:

[image]

my expected output like this:

```
    Itemcode    description   category   qty    good    defective
    661-00060   Logic Board                4     3           1
```

I want to take sum of good quantity and sum of defective quantity ? So how I can re-write the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding 1, add `tbsd.QTY - tbsd.RESERVEDQTY`:

```
SELECT 
    tbsd.ITEMCODE, 
    tmi.ITEMNAME AS DESCRIPTION,
    tmi.CATEGORYCODE AS CATEGORY, 
    SUM(tbsd.QTY - tbsd.RESERVEDQTY) AS QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' THEN tbsd.QTY - tbsd.RESERVEDQTY ELSE 0 END) AS GOOD,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE' THEN tbsd.QTY - tbsd.RESERVEDQTY ELSE 0 END) AS DEFECTIVE 
FROM T_BOE_STOCK_DETAIL tbsd
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_MASTER_ITEM 
    ON tbsd.ITEMCODE = tmi.ITEMCODE
WHERE 
    tbsd.QTY - tbsd.RESERVEDQTY > 0
GROUP BY 
    tbsd.ITEMCODE, 
    tmi.ITEMNAME,
    tmi.CATEGORYCODE
HAVING SUM(tbsd.qty - tbsd.ReservedQty) > 0 
ORDER BY 
    tmi.categoryCode,
    tbsd.itemCode
```

*As a side note, please alias your tables to increase readability.*

Comment: thanks a lot. this is worked for me..i shall be very thank full to you

Answer (score 2):

Your lines in the top query:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) Good,
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Defective
```

It is summing the number of *rows* that are `DOCTYPE = 'GOOD'` or `DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE'`.

You want the number of `qty` that are `DOCTYPE = 'GOOD'` and `DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE'`. Also, per your "total" Qty line, you probably want to subtract any `ReservedQty`.

Try to replace the lines with:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' THEN qty - ReservedQty ELSE 0 END  ) Good,
SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE' THEN qty - ReservedQty ELSE 0 END) Defective
```

Comment: dear sir instead of qty we have to add qty-reserved qty

Comment: I've just revised the answer. :-)